# Как сконвертировать в UNIX формат время вида "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS+0000" (Python)

Tags: python

У меня есть время вида

```
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS+0000
```

Как мне на Python получить с него unix timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pip install python-dateutil`

```py
from dateutil.parser import parse

print(
  repr(parse(
    '2020-12-12T10:11:15+0000'
  ))
)
# datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 12, 10, 11, 15, tzinfo=tzlocal())
```